# Displaying value in one combobox which depends from another combobox in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

Currently I'm working on a form where it requires the user to select a specific floor from a combobox named floorCbo. once the user has selected the floor, the units of the floor will appear in another combobox named unitCbo. I have tried on the code below but nothing seems to appear in the unitCbo combobox after selecting a floor on floorCbo.

```
 private void floorCboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   String selectedvalue = floorCbo.getSelectedItem().toString();

   if  (floorCbo.equals("1ST FLOOR")){

       unitCbo.add(this, "UNIT 1A");
        unitCbo.add(this, "UNIT 1B");
         unitCbo.add(this, "UNIT 1C");
          unitCbo.add(this, "UNIT 1D");
           unitCbo.add(this, "UNI T1E");
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to have
`if (selectedvalue.equals("1ST FLOOR"))`? Currently you are checking equality on the combobox object rather than it's value

Comment: i have tried your suggestion of code but i still am having error where the combo box values for unitCbo are not appearing based on my selection on  floorCbo.

Comment: I'm only used to using a JComboBox, but in that case a call to 'box2.removeAllItems()' then 'box2.addItem("item1") ...' would have done as you wanted. What type is your 'unitCbo'? Also, just to be sure is "1ST FLOOR" exactly the text set in your first combobox, including case sensitivity?